# How is modular arithmetic used in cryptography and matrices?

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic, inverse, cryptography

I am a high school Mathematics C student, preparing for an upcoming exam. Sorry in advance for the long post below.

The problem I have been presented with it to **encode** the message "**Targetbm**". The method for encoding requires you to place each character into a **2x2 matrix**, the results are:

|T, A, R, G| |E, T, B, M| (These are a 2, 2x2 matrices ordering in the order; **1st to 4th element**).

Then you convert the letters into their corresponding placement in the alphabet (**e.g** a = 1 or 27, y = 25 or -1, and z = 26 or 0). It's modulo, so 52 would also = z.

After we have converted the matrices into numbers, the result is this;
|20, 1, 18, 7| and |5, 20, 2, 13|

Then you multiply by the encoding key:
|2, 0, -2, -2|

So the first matrix will result in:|38, -2, 22, -14| and the second: |-30, -40, -22, -26|

Finally, you convert these numbers using modulo and you get the following:

|L, X, V, L| and |V, L, D, Z|

Once this has been completed, this is where trouble ensues, it asks you to **decode** it. I started by **inverting** the **encoding key** and multiplying the matrices by the inverted encoding key ( |1/2, 0, -1/2, -1/2| ). After applying this, the first matrix resulted in |-6, -12, 5, -6|.

Although the first letter converts successfully to the letter 'T' (I'm assuming by coincidence), **none** of the others did. As far as I'm aware, there is an additional, or different method required that employs 'modulo inversion'. All my research turned up was the use of **greatest common denominators**, however, I'm unaware of how to apply this to my revision question.

Comment: You're running into an issue partly because $26$ is not prime. Additionally your coding matrix elements have a common factor of $2$, which divides $26$, meaning you have immediately lost information. (To see this, run your coding with |G, N, E, G|)  Are you allowed to specify a different modular base, like 29?

Comment: Yes, specifying a different modular base is allowed. One base that was suggested, was 27, introducing the space character: " ". If I changed the base to 27, would you be able to run me through the steps of completing this question? Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into an issue partly because $26$ is not prime. Additionally your coding matrix elements have a common factor of $2$, which divides $26$, meaning you have immediately lost information. (To see this, run your coding with |G, N, E, G|).

So you need to specify a different modular base. Adding a space as a value zero (or 27) we can extend to $\bmod 27$.

Running through the process $\bmod 27$, rather than $\bmod 26$, we need to find the integer inverse of the coding matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}\frac 12 & 0 \\ -\frac 12& -\frac 12\end{pmatrix} \equiv \begin{pmatrix}\frac {28}2 & 0 \\ \frac {26}2& \frac {26}2\end{pmatrix} \equiv \begin{pmatrix}14 & 0 \\ 13& 13\end{pmatrix} \bmod 27$

Then the coding /decoding  for TARG looks like:

$\begin{pmatrix}T & A \\ R& G\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}20 & 1 \\18& 7\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}20 & 1 \\ 18 & 7\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ -2& -2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}38 & -2 \\ 22& -14\end{pmatrix} \equiv \begin{pmatrix}11 & 25 \\ 22& 13\end{pmatrix} \bmod 27$

Giving a code of KYVM, and decoding in the same way:

$\begin{pmatrix}11 & 25 \\ 22& 13\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}14 & 0 \\ 13& 13\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}479 & 325 \\ 477 & 169\end{pmatrix} \equiv \begin{pmatrix}20 & 1 \\ 18 & 7\end{pmatrix} \bmod 27$

I'm not completely sure this is safe; we might run into problems if our characters have a lot of multiples of 3 included, due to factors of $27$. But it works for your two example strings.